# Finding the partial fraction of $x+21/2(2x+3)(3x-2)$

Tags: partial-fractions

$x+21 / 2(2x+3)(3x-2)$

The 2 in the denominator represents a problem for me:

$x+21 / 2(2x+3)(3x-2) = A / 2(2x+3) * B / 2(3x-2)$
$x+21 = A(2)(3x-2) + B(2x+3)$

Comment: Have a look at this to format your fractions in MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The expression you have written means $$x + \frac{21}{2} \times (2x+3) \times (3x - 2)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{x+21}{(2x+3)(3x-2)}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot (\frac{A}{2x+3}+\frac{B}{3x-2})$$
Then continue.